# If $G$ is a prime graph of order $v$, then the independence number of $G$ satisfies $\text{ind}(G) \geqslant \lfloor \frac{v}{2} \rfloor$.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Can I get help with proving this statement? I get stuck on showing the independence number of a prime graph of order $v$. I will be considering two cases?

Definition:
Let $\textit{G=(V(G),E(G))}$ be a graph with $p$ vertices. A \emph{bijection} \textit{f:V(G)}$\rightarrow \lbrace1,2,\cdots ,p \rbrace$ is called a \emph{prime labeling} if for each edge $e=\lbrace uv \rbrace \in E(G)$ we have $gcd(f(u),f(v))=1$. A graph which admits a prime labeling is called a \emph{prime graph}.

Definition:
The independence number of a graph G is the maximum cardinality of an independent set of vertices. It is denoted by $ind(G)$ or $\alpha(G)$.

Definition:
Let $G$ be undirected graph. $A\subseteq V(G)$ is an independent set if no two vertices in $A$ share an edge. For all $u,v \in A$, $(u,v) \not \in E(G)$.

This is my work, but I think its wrong. Suppose $G$ is a prime graph with n vertices $v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_n$. We denote $\alpha(G)$ be the the independence number of a graph $G$. The independence number is the maximum cardinality of independent set in graph $G$ in which independent set is no two points are adjacent with each other. The order of $G$ is denoted by $\vert V(G) \vert =n$ and the size of $G$ is denoted by $\vert E(G)\vert = n$. To show that the independence number of graph $G$ we considered two cases. We define a labeling $f: V(G)\rightarrow\lbrace1,2,\cdots, n\rbrace$.

**Case 1:** If $n$ is even where $n\in \mathbb{Z^+}$\
In this case, since our $n$ is even then we can find a maximum independent set. Also, since we define our labeling from $f: V(G)\rightarrow \lbrace1,2,\cdots, n\rbrace$ and we get the even labels then applying the formula of independence number of graph $G$ we get $\alpha(G) \geqslant \left\lfloor \dfrac{v}{2} \right \rfloor$. Thus, $G$ is a prime graph.

**Case 2:** If $n$ is odd $n\in \mathbb{Z^+}$. \
In this case, since our $n$ is odd then we can not find a maximum independent set. We define our labeling from $f: V(G)\rightarrow\lbrace1,2,\cdots, n\rbrace$. Using the labeling defined, we get the odd labels and we apply the formula of independence number of graph $G$ we get $\alpha(G) < \left\lfloor \dfrac{v}{2} \right\rfloor$. Hence our independence number of graph $G$ is $\alpha(G) < \left\lfloor \dfrac{v}{2}\right\rfloor$, Thus $G$ is not a prime graph

Comment: What is a prime graph of order $v$?  Do you mean acyclic?

Comment: Graph of order v is the set of vertices in a graph G. Let G=(V(G),E(G)) be a graph with p vertices. A bijection f:V(G) mapping to {1,2,…,p} is called a prime labeling if for each edge e=uv in G we have gcd(f(v),f(u))=1. A graph which admits a prime labeling is called a prime graph

Comment: You haven't indicated where you are stuck.  Saying that you are stuck on what amounts to the entire question is very unhelpful.  Are you stuck on the definitions used?  Are you unable to transfer the concept of independent number into a statement about $\{1,2,\ldots,p\}$?  Are you able to get some lower bound but it is not high enough to satisfy the question?  There is so much room to be more specific about where you are stuck.  Please edit your question.

Comment: I don't know where I'm going to start. I have ideas but I think it is wrong. How can I show that the independence number \text{ind}(G) \geqslant \lfloor \frac{v}{2} \rfloor?

Comment: I will be considering two cases? Even and odd?

Comment: My suggestion for where to start: make sure you understand the definition of independence number and the definition of prime graph.  Then translate the statement "the independence number (of a prime graph) is $\ge k$" into a statement about GCDs of numbers.  Then it makes sense to think about optimizing $k$ and looking at cases, but first you **must** do the legwork of following definitions since it is clear that you haven't done so.

Comment: You have ideas that you think are wrong?  Write them down!  A question with incorrect thoughts is ten times better than a question with no thoughts.  The fact that you didn't write out your thoughts is exactly the reason why your question was voted down.

Comment: @JMDeOcampo Please include the definition of a *prime graph* into the question.

Answer (score 2):

Define a graph $G=(V,E)$ with $V=\{1,...,p\}$ and $E=\{(n,m)\in V\mid \gcd(n,m)=1\}$. Any *prime graph* on $p$ vertices can be obtained from $G$ by removing some edges. Removing edges can only increase $\alpha(G)$, so it suffices to study this graph instead of general prime graphs.

Define the vertex set $V':=\{v\in V \mid v\equiv 0\pmod{2}\}$, i.e. $V'$ is the set of vertices with associated even numbers. As it turns out, $V'$ is independent because $\gcd(v,w)=2$ for $v,w\in V'$. Also, since it contains the even numbers, it contains (approximately) half the vertice of $G$, more precisely 
$|V'|\geq\lfloor p/2\rfloor$.

Comment: How obvious it is? Why it suffices to study $V'$ instead of $V&? What example of graph that we can consider? With even vertices?

Comment: @JMDeOcampo $V'$ is an independent set. We do not study it *instead* of $V$. We study this graph instead of general prime graphs because every prime graph on $p$ vertices  is a subgraph of this graph (think about it). $V'$ contains every second vertex from $V$ (all the even ones). So it has (approximately) half of its size.

Comment: In cycle $C_6$, the independence number is greater? In $C_5$ the independence number is lesser?

Comment: @JMDeOcampo Greater/lesser than what?

Comment: In $C_6$ $\alpha(G) \geqslant \left\lfloor \dfrac{v}{2} \right \rfloor$ while in $C_5$ $\alpha(G) \leqslant \left\lfloor \dfrac{v}{2} \right \rfloor$

Comment: @JMDeOcampo $\alpha(C_5)=2=\lfloor 5/2\rfloor$. $\leq$ does not exclude $\geq$ in the case of equality.

Comment: So, it is not  prime graph?

Comment: @JMDeOcampo Of course, why not? It satisfies the inequality.

Comment: I'm little bit confused, but I'm trying to understand the thoughts. In my work, where do I start editing ? My work is wrong?

Comment: @JMDeOcampo It is a bit confusing. I have the feeling you should get more confortable with some of the concepts. E.g. why should there be no *maximal independent set* for odd $n$? Of course there is. The compete resoning is missing in your post. I recommend to continue this discussen in chat if necessary.

Comment: I can't chat you because my reputation is very small. Do you have an email?

Comment: @JMDeOcampo I see. Still, I prefer to discuss here. Try to understand what I wrote or think about your own proof again. And if you have any concrete questions: please do not hesitate to ask.

Comment: $V'$ is complement of V? Or $V'$ is just a notation for independence number?

Comment: @JMDeOcampo $V'\subseteq V$ is just a set of *some* vertices of the graph defined in my answer. I could have named it $W$ or $X$ or anything. $V'$ alone does not mean anything.

Comment: Why is it there's no maximal independent set in odd? Why in even we can find maximal independent set?

Comment: @JMDeOcampo This is false. We can always find one.

Comment: This two statements, I can consider it as Case 1 and Case 2?

Comment: @JMDeOcampo You can (and you did), but why do you want to distinguish even and odd cases?

Comment: To see that if it is true when v is odd  then the independence number is $\alpha(G) \leqslant \left\lfloor \dfrac{v}{2} \right \rfloor$ and also it is not prime graph.

Comment: @JMDeOcampo This is not true in general. Consider a graph without edges. It is a prime graph but its vertex set is independent and has size $v=|V|$. It also works for odd $v$.

Comment: So, it is not necessary to show two cases? I can simply prove it directly?

Comment: @JMDeOcampo Yes. Because I did this in my answer. This is a full proof.

Comment: What will happen if we do not remove some edges?

Comment: @JMDeOcampo Nothing. The demonstrated graph $G$ is a valid prime graph too.

Comment: Hmm. Can you help me to revise my own proof sir?

Comment: @JMDeOcampo We already did. Your case analysis contains wrong statements (no maximal independent set for odd $v$). Also it seems you do not need a case analysis at all. I recomment you rethinking the complete proof and starting another question. The proof, as written down here is hard to follow. Also try using consistent notation, e.g. $\mathrm{ind}(G)$ vs. $\alpha(G)$, $n$ vs. $p$ vs. $v$, $|E(G)|=n$ vs. $|V(G)|=n$ etc. And this comment section is getting too long.

Comment: @JMDeOcampo I do not want to be harsh. Sorry if it felt like this. Try giving a short and consistent proof. Try for format your post nicely. So more people are going to help you there.

Comment: Thank you for helping me sir. Also, for your time to answer my questions. Have a nice day!

Comment: Hmm. Noted sir. Its okay, I understand.